# Object required error when clicking command button

Tags: excel, vba, object

I'm receiving an "Object required" error when trying to access my user form. It highlights the following code:

```
Sub DataEntry()
    ServiceUpgradesDatEntry.Show
End Sub
```

I've double checked that the name is correct. I'm still new to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Tools - Options - General` in the VBE and change Error Trapping to `Break in Class Module`. There is an error in the userform's Initialize event, but the VBE isn't set to break in the userform's class module so it breaks on the line that sent you into the class module (the .Show line).

Once you've set that, clicking Debug on the error will highlight the line that's actually producing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Treat your userform like an object and declare and instantiate it accordingly.

```
Public Sub DataEntry()

    Dim dataEntryForm As ServiceUpgradesDatEntry

    ' Create an instance of the form
    Set dataEntryForm = New ServiceUpgradesDatEntry
    ' Show the form
    dataEntryForm.Show
    ' If the form was opened as Modal, then the code here will only run
    ' once the form has been hidden/closed
    ' Now destroy the object
    Set dataEntryForm = Nothing

End Sub
```